# How to break out of case and repeat program until user chooses to exit

Tags: java

I have to make a simple calculator in java that calls methods instead of repeating the entire program over and over again. All of my methods work, and it allows the user to make incorrect choices for as long as they want until a correct choice is made. The problem I am having is that it won't break out of a case after the operation is done and the answer is given.

```
package menuDrivenCalculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MenuDrivenCalculator {
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int menuOption = getMenuOption();

        while (menuOption < 1 || menuOption > 6) {
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, " + menuOption + " is not a valid choice. Please try again.");
            menuOption = getMenuOption();
            if (menuOption >= 1 && menuOption <= 6) {
                break;
            }
        }

        while (menuOption >= 1 && menuOption <= 6) {

            switch (menuOption) {
            case 1:

                System.out.print("What is the first number? ");
                double operand1 = getOperand();
                System.out.print("What is the second number?");
                double operand2 = getOperand();

                double add = add(operand1, operand2);
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + add);

                break;

            case 2:

                System.out.print("What is the first number? ");
                operand1 = getOperand();
                System.out.print("What is the second number?");
                operand2 = getOperand();

                double subtract = subtract(operand1, operand2);
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + subtract);

                break;

            case 3:

                System.out.print("What is the first number? ");
                operand1 = getOperand();
                System.out.print("What is the second number?");
                operand2 = getOperand();

                double multiply = multiply(operand1, operand2);
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + multiply);
                break;

            case 4:

                System.out.print("What is the first number? ");
                operand1 = getOperand();
                System.out.print("What is the second number?");
                operand2 = getOperand();

                double divide = divide(operand1, operand2);
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + divide);

                break;

            case 5:

                System.out.print("What is the lower limit? ");
                operand1 = getOperand();
                System.out.print("What is the upper limit?");
                operand2 = getOperand();

                double random = random(operand1, operand2);
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + random);

                break;

            case 6:
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                return;

            }

        }
}

public static int getMenuOption() {

    System.out.println("Menu");
    System.out.println("1. Add");
    System.out.println("2. Subtract");
    System.out.println("3. Multiply");
    System.out.println("4. Divide");
    System.out.println("5. Generate a random number");
    System.out.println("6. Quit\n");

    System.out.print("What would you like to do? ");
    int menuOption = input.nextInt();

    return menuOption;
}

public static double getOperand() {

    double operand = input.nextDouble();

    return operand;
}

public static double add(double operand1, double operand2) {

    double add = (operand1 + operand2);

    return add;
}

public static double subtract(double operand1, double operand2) {

    double subtract = (operand1 - operand2);

    return subtract;
}

public static double multiply(double operand1, double operand2) {

    double multiply = (operand1 * operand2);

    return multiply;
}

public static double divide(double operand1, double operand2) {

    double divide = 0;
    if (operand2 == 0) {
        divide = Double.NaN;
    } else if (operand2 != 0) {
        divide = (operand1 / operand2);
    }
    return divide;
}

public static double random(double operand1, double operand2) {

    double random = Math.random() * operand2 + operand1;

    return random;
}
}
```

What is happening is the program prompts the user for input for the same operation over and over again until you manually stop the program from running. I've tried putting the entire thing in different types of loops and nothing has changed.

Comment: Your need is not very clear.

Comment: remove the `while-loop` which contains `switch` and remain your `switch`. Or include the whole thing inside `main` if you want user can perform different operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code for performing the operations is inside a loop (`while (menuOption >= 1 && menuOption <= 6)`) the program will continue to cycle on the last chosen operation.

You need a loop that includes also the `getMenuOption()` method so the user can choose another operation.

To do so, instead of having 2 separate loops, you could have just 1 to take care of everything (remember also you could use the `default` case inside the `switch`).

Since it seems homework I will not give you the complete solution but if you have other specific doubts let us know.

Comment: Thanks! The information you gave me was enough to get my issue fixed. And I really appreciate you not giving me the final answer since it was a homework project.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want it to repeat over,why put the switch statement in while loop?
Replace 'while' with 'if' in your code

Comment: I need the whole thing to repeat, i just don't want a single case to repeat itself over and over. That's the issue I'm having.

Comment: Then you can repeat the entire code in a single loop instead of 2, so the getMenuOption() method will be repeated.